# Converter array de objetos para um array de arrays

Tags: javascript, array

**Como realizar a conversão da string (array de objetos):**

```
 [
  {"id":1,"nome":"Maluf","cpf":"007.519.591-20"},
  {"id":2,"nome":"Paulo Ricardo","cpf":"565.232.591-02"},
  {"id":3,"nome":"Joaquim Barbosa","cpf":"007.519.699-32"}, 
  {"id":4,"nome":"Dilma Folgada","cpf":"007.963.000-02"}
 ]
```

**Para um array de arrays:**

```
[
  [1,'Maluf','007.519.591-20'],
  [2,'Paulo Ricardo','565.232.591-02'],
  [3,'Joaquim Barbosa','007.519.699-32'], 
  [4,'Dilma Folgada','007.963.000-02']
 ]
```

> **Observação: Note que no resultado esperado eu não tenho os atributos. id, nome, cpf**

**Explicando a Situação:**

Eu tenho um componente `Ext.data.ArrayStore` (Componente da biblioteca EXTJS)

```
  var dependentes = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [
      {name: 'id'},
      {name: 'nomeDependente'},
      {name: 'cpfDependente'}
    ]
  });
```

E tenho um array assim:

```
  var dados = [
    [1, Eduardo, '007.519.591-70'],
    [2, 'Fabio', '222.519.111-70']
  ];
```

Os dados do array são fixos, correto?
Mas preciso criar os dados desse array de forma dinâmica,
pois esses só virão na forma de string, não é possível eu trazer 
os dados via banco de dados, a ferramenta que trabalho me limita.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aqui fica uma versão com JavaScript nativo, é bem simples:

```
var convertida = original.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(chave) {
        return obj[chave];
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8k3o1v80/

O código tem dois `.map()`. O primeiro é porque começas com uma array (de objetos), e queres manter uma array com o mesmo numero de elementos. O segundo `.map()` é para transformar/mapear cada objeto numa array. E podes fazer isso retornando na callback desse `.map()` o valor dessa chave: `obj[chave]`.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, me ajudou muito. Grato por me ajudar em meu trabalho.

Comment: @durtto fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Da uma olhada nesse algoritmo, veja se ajuda.

```
  var objArr = []; //Array final
  var myObj = [
    {"id":1,"nome":"Maluf","cpf":"007.519.591-20"},
    {"id":2,"nome":"Paulo Ricardo","cpf":"565.232.591-02"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"Joaquim Barbosa","cpf":"007.519.699-32"}, 
    {"id":4,"nome":"Dilma Folgada","cpf":"007.963.000-02"}
   ];

   //Aqui percorremos seu obj inicial e criamos o conteudo do array final
   $.each(myObj,function(idx,obj){
    objArr.push([obj.id,obj.nome,obj.cpf]);  
   });

   //Output com resultado no console
   console.info('Seu objeto array', objArr);
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Simplificando um pouco mais!!

```
var vetor = [
  {"id":1,"nome":"Maluf","cpf":"007.519.591-20"},
  {"id":2,"nome":"Paulo Ricardo","cpf":"565.232.591-02"},
  {"id":3,"nome":"Joaquim Barbosa","cpf":"007.519.699-32"}, 
  {"id":4,"nome":"Dilma Folgada","cpf":"007.963.000-02"}
].map(item => [item.id,item.nome,item.cpf])

console.log(vetor)
```