# Converter json para array utilizando javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um objeto

```
{
         '1': {
          'nome': 'pedro',
          'idade': 2,
        },
        '2': {
          'maria': maria,
          'idade': 5,

        }
}
```

Array

```
[{
        '1': {
          'nome': 'pedro',
          'idade': 2,

        },
        '2': {
          'maria': maria,
          'idade': 5,

        }
}]
```

Eu preciso verificar se é um objeto como o exemplo e se for transformar em array conforme

modelo em javascript puro

Comment: Esta pergunta já tem uma resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105978/converter-array-de-objetos-para-um-array-de-arrays

Comment: @Leandro Boa noite! Não é a mesma coisa eu quero converter para uma array de objetos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 * @param {Object} nested
 * @returns {Array}
*/

function nestedToArray(nested) {
    let arrayOfObjects = [];

    for (const prop in nested) {
        if (nested.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            arrayOfObjects.push(nested[prop]);
          } 
    }
    return arrayOfObjects;
}
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Perfeito!! Resolveu aqui!!!