# Transformar Array de String em Array de Objeto

Tags: javascript, json, revisão-de-código

Tenho o seguinte `Array` de string:

`["TagFuncao:CN Evento:TODOS", "TagFuncao:DOC.AGRO.INDUS Evento:TODOS"]`

Preciso transformar esse Array em uma Array de Objetos onde `TagFuncao` e `Evento` é propriedades do Objeto, e `CN` e `TODOS` seja o valor correspondente de cada propriedade.

Fiz alguns testes no console do navegador e cheguei ao seguinte resultado:

```
var newArr = r.map(i => {
var x = i.split(' ');
var p1 = x[0].replace('TagFuncao:','')
var p2 = x[1].replace('Evento:', '')
var obj = {
        tagFuncao: p1,
        evento: p2
    }

    return obj
})
```

Resultado:

`[{tagFuncao: "CN", evento: "TODOS"}, {tagFuncao: "DOC.AGRO.INDUS", evento: "TODOS"}]`

A principio resolve o meu problema, mas não parece ser uma das melhores formas de fazer.

Pergunta:

Existe outras formas de fazer isso e chegar ao mesmo resultado que não seja desta forma?

Comment: Veja se não é isto que precisa, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105978/converter-array-de-objetos-para-um-array-de-arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segue uma solução com regex

```
const array = [
  "TagFuncao:CN Evento:TODOS",
  "TagFuncao:DOC.AGRO.INDUS Evento:TODOS",
];

const nu_array = array.map((item) => {
  return { tagFuncao: item.match(/[^:]*\s/g)[0], evento: item.match(/[^:]*$/g)[0] };
});
```

- Explicação

Selecione todos os itens depois de : até o próximo espaço

```
/[^:]*\s/g
```

Selecione todos os itens depois de : até o final do texto

```
/[^:]*$/g
```

o [0] é pra pegar o primeiro item do match, pois a função retorna um array

- Resultado

```
[ { tagFuncao: 'CN ', evento: 'TODOS' },
  { tagFuncao: 'DOC.AGRO.INDUS ', evento: 'TODOS' } ]
```

Comment: Ficou bom. Eu havia imaginado fazer dois regex para analisar segundo a norma ECMAScript mas você provou que eu estava enganado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Vale lembrar que essa solução funciona somente se as strings tiverem exatamente TagFuncao e Evento nesta ordem, e nenhuma outra informação. Para aceitar mais propriedades com nomes diferentes (ou somente essas duas em outra ordem, etc), as outras respostas são melhores. Como melhoria, sugiro trocar `*` por `+`, assim força a ter pelo menos um caractere (senão vai retornar string vazia caso o texto termine com `"Evento:"`)

Comment: @hkotsubo com a inclusão do operador `+` gera um erro na função ao pegar o primeiro valor do match [0] sendo assim, caso não vier valor nenhum ele torna o valor vazio, acho que é uma solução boa para o problema. `{..., evento : '' }`

Answer (score 6):

Assumindo que tens sempre um espaço entre os valores que queres ler podes fazer um mapeamento com um `reduce` dentro para extrair esses valores.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```js
const data = ["TagFuncao:CN Evento:TODOS", "TagFuncao:DOC.AGRO.INDUS Evento:TODOS"];

const objectificar = (string) => string.split(' ').reduce((obj, str) => {
    const [key, value] = str.split(':');
    return {
      ...obj,
      [key]: value
    }
  }, {});

const dataComObjetos = data.map(objectificar);
console.log(dataComObjetos);
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é muito diferente do que fez mas possui a vantagem de não ter que alterar o algorítimo caso venha criar uma chave diferente no futuro:

```js
let arr = [
  "TagFuncao:CN Evento:TODOS",
  "TagFuncao:DOC.AGRO.INDUS Evento:TODOS",
  "teste:-23 verdadeiro:false" //Chave de teste
];

//Função de conversão do texto para objeto, movi para fora do map para facilitar a leitura
function paraObjeto(texto) {
  let resultado = new Object(); //Cria um objeto vazio.
  propriedades = texto.split(' '); // Separa as propriedades pelo espaço entre elas.
  propriedades.forEach((item) => { //Para cada proriedade..
    chaveValor = item.split(':'); //Separa chave do valor
    resultado[chaveValor[0]] = chaveValor[1]; //Adiciona ao objeto a chave e seu respectivo valor
  });
  return resultado; //Retorna o objeto preenchido
}

let objetos = arr.map(item => paraObjeto(item));

console.log(objetos);
```

Havia possibilidade de adequar cada string ao [padrão JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) de fazer a analize com [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) mas para a string ser analisada cada par chave/valor teriam que estar em conformidade a norma [ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/) para [identificadores](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-identifier-names) e [literais](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar-literals) o que iria demandar duas [expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) cujo o esforço de construção não valeriam o resultado obtido.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem nenhum problema com seu código, mas eu sugeriria reduzir a quantidade de variáveis criada, se você usa a variável apenas uma vez, provavelmente ela não precisa existir. Fora isso, seu código tem a característica já comentada de não ser dinâmico, se futuramente a estrutura mudar, o código precisará ser alterado, porém isso não necessariamente um problema, se não pretende alterar sua estrutura está ótimo assim

A melhor (na maioria dos casos) forma de resolver isso é alterando o código que gera esse array de forma que use um formato padronizado, como JSON, CSV ou semelhante. mas se você não tem acesso a esse código ou é complicado demais altera-lo...

Uma solução é transformar as strings em JSONs válidos e então fazer o *parse*. Isso é possível sem o uso de expressções regulares:

```js
var oldArray = [
  'TagFuncao:CN Evento:TODOS',
  'TagFuncao:DOC.AGRO.INDUS Evento:TODOS',
  'teste:-23 verdadeiro:false'
];

var json = oldArray.map(elements => `{"${elements.split(':').join('":"').split(' ').join('","')}"}`);

console.log(json);

var newArray = oldArray.map(elements => JSON.parse(`{"${elements.split(':').join('":"').split(' ').join('","')}"}`));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o porque negativarem. Essa resposta ao meu ver é boa. Quem deu o negativo poderia fazer o favor de me explicar o porque não a considerou útil?